# Bash scripting issue for a bifurcation diagram data generation

Tags: bash, scripts, files

I've a Bash script that doesn't work and I don't know why... My Bouncingball program runs perfectly when I call it manually

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "enter starting value"
read start
echo "enter size of steps"
read steps
echo "enter number of steps"
read number
echo "enter the suitable pecisiion"
read precision


for i in $(number)
    do
        exec ./home/antoine/Bouncingball/bin/Debug/Boungingball 0.9 120 "$start+($i*$steps)" 3.5 0.95 "$precision"
        for j in 200
            do
                $(sed -n ($(precision)-200+$(j))'p' impactMap.dat) >> diagbif.dat
            done
    done
```

What I want to do with this code is generate an impactMap.dat file with bouncingball and store the 200 last lines in diagbif.dat, then increment some variable of bouncing ball and angain store the 200 last lines of impactMap.dat at the end of diagbif.dat . If someone can help me make it work it would be awesome !

Comment: Hi noxygen, welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I'm afraid your question isn't a good fit for Ask Ubuntu (or even Stack Overflow, which specializes in programming). Questions on StackExchange are meant to be useful to at least two people, and yours isn't. You might find better help on other websites, like ubuntuforums.org. Good luck with your programming quest, and keep at it!

Comment: @Flimm - I'd argue that the question is actually a good fit for SO (or potentially UL.SE, given its more technical userbase), since the underlying problems seem to be in Bash scripting in general. (And even if they aren't, SO is filled with "why isn't this working?" types of questions that are accepted by the community.)

Comment: sorry for that... I wasn't sure about posting here but I really needed help so I thought "let's give it a try". I understand your point of view and again I'm sorry.

Comment: @noxygen: Nothing to be sorry about!

Comment: @Flimm I strongly disagree. Answers to this question elucidate programming and shell principles that make this question relevant to a huge audience. This is on topic here and would be on topic on Stack Overflow too (but it should not be posted in both places at once, of course).

Answer (score 3):

Problems with your version:

- `for i in $(number)` does not run `NUMBER` times, but once with `i=NUMBER`.
- `./home/antoine/...` starts with a `.`, so is interpreted as a path relative to your current directory. Since you probably run it from `/home/antoine`, it will interpret it as `/home/antonine/home/antoine/...`, which probably doesn't work. Delete the leading `.` to make it an absolute path.
- Using a loop and `sed` to extract the last 200 lines could be done more efficiently with `tail`.
- Mathematics needs to be enclosed in `$(( ... ))` or it will not be correctly interpreted.

Try (not tested):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "enter starting value"
read start
echo "enter size of steps"
read steps
echo "enter number of steps"
read number
echo "enter the suitable pecisiion"
read precision

for i in $(seq $number); do
    /home/antoine/Bouncingball/bin/Debug/Boungingball 0.9 120 $(($start+($i*$steps))) 3.5 0.95 "$precision"
    tail -n 200 impactMap.dat >> diagbif.dat
done
```

Comment: Note that within `(( ... ))`, variables to not require the leading `$`, so it's a bit more tidy to read: `$((start+i*steps))`

Answer (score 1):

1- Don't use `exec` like that: it will *replace* the running shell process (i.e. your script) with the exec'ed program. So, when the program ends, control will not pass back to your script.

From a terminal, type `help exec` for more details.

2- Use `read -p` to have a custom prompt:

```
read -p "enter starting value: " start
read -p "enter size of steps: " steps
read -p "enter number of steps: " number
read -p "enter the suitable precision: " precision
```

3- Doing this

```
$(sed ...) >> diagbif.dat
```

will run sed, put the output on that command line and then attempt to *execute the output as shell commands*. I assume that's not what you're trying to do. Only use `$(...)` if you want to capture the output of a command. Use `tail` as suggested or:

```
sed -n "$((precision-200+j))p" impactMap.dat >> diagbif.dat
```

4- +1 for chronitis's suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer thanks to glenn jackman and chronitis :

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/antoine/Bouncingball/bin/Debug/

read -p "enter starting value: " start
read -p "enter ending value: " ending
read -p "enter number of steps: " number
read -p "enter the suitable precision: " precision
read -p "enter the diagram definition: " diagram
steps=$(echo "($ending - $start) / $number" | bc -l )

for i in $(seq $number); do
    if (( $i % 100 == 0)); then
        rm impactMap.dat
        echo "!!!=== ETAPE : $i sur $number ===!!!"
    fi
    /home/antoine/Bouncingball/bin/Debug/Bouncingball 0.9 120 $(echo "$start + $i * $steps" | bc -l) 3.5 0.95 "$precision" 1
    tail -n "$diagram" impactMap.dat >> diagbif.dat
done

xmgrace diagbif.dat -autoscale xy
```

here we go ! 
I post this answer because I'm sure it can help people with variables manipulation and whatsoever. I hope it'll help someone !

ps : last line is made to display the datas on a graphic with xmgrace.